# Randomize Text (JS) in Input (HTML) on Reload

Tags: javascript, html

I want to randomize letters and numbers, something like

`let r = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
console.log("random", r);`

but insert it in a text input HTML field. I have already managed to plug in texts from a list, but I want it completely random and to follow with an @something.com.

For example, I want the input field, on every refresh to have something like the following:

8ut5fgh8@gmail.com

0okmnhy4@gmail.com

s5g7j9l0@gmail.com

The characters before the @gmail.com should be 8 chars long.

Thanks for your help. This is a snippet of what I have already done"

```js
var texts = [
  "@gmail.com",
  "@yahoo.com",
  "@xdxd.com"
];

document.getElementById('email0').value = texts[Math.floor(Math.random()*texts.length)];
```

```html
E-mail: </br><input type="text" id="email0" name="email"><br>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you figured out how to make a domain part - do the rest by analogy.

```js
var texts = [
  "@gmail.com",
  "@yahoo.com",
  "@xdxd.com"
];
var chars = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']

function randomEmail(length) {
  let result = ''
  for (let i = 0; i <= length; i++) {
    result += chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)]
  }
  return result + texts[Math.floor(Math.random() * texts.length)]
}
document.getElementById('email0').value = randomEmail(8)
```

```html
E-mail: <br><input type="text" id="email0" name="email"><br>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

```js
var texts = [
  "@gmail.com",
  "@yahoo.com",
  "@xdxd.com"
];
function random() {
  var text = "";
  var ch = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
  for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    text += ch.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * ch.length));
  return text;
}

let str = random()+texts[Math.floor(Math.random()*texts.length)];
document.getElementById('email0').value = str
```

```html
<input id="email0">
```

Comment: You'r a genius. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

this is another way to do it using arrays and join and assuming you only want small letters in your random emails.

```
let texts = [
  "@gmail.com",
  "@yahoo.com",
  "@xdxd.com"
];
let alphnum = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
let randomChoice = [texts[Math.floor(Math.random() * texts.length)]]

for (let index = 0; index < 8; index++) {
  const element = alphnum[Math.floor(Math.random() * alphnum.length)];
  randomChoice.unshift(element)
}
let randomChoiceString = randomChoice.join("")

document.getElementById('email0').value = randomChoiceString
```